# What does node mean in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, nested-sets

Could anyone explain what node means in MySQL?

This one is talking about nested set.

I am reading a document from Codeigniter's wiki and I am not sure what I am supposed to add for $node.

```
getSubTreeAsHTML (line 704)

Renders the fields for each node starting at the given node

    * return: Sample HTML render of tree

string getSubTreeAsHTML (array $node, [array $fields = array()])

    * array $node: The node to start with
    * array $fields: The fields to display for each node
```

Comment: How does this relate to mysql ?

Comment: Nested sets are a relational database concept, just not MySQL in particular.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code you are looking at is part of [BackendPro](http://www.kaydoo.co.uk/projects/backendpro).  The full code of the function [can be viewed here](http://trac2.assembla.com/backendpro/browser/trunk/system/application/models/Nested_sets_model.php).

"Node" in this case refers to a data node of a [nested set](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nested_set_model).  Nested sets are nice because they allow you to quickly select a whole branch of a hierarchy with only the starting node.

It looks like the function specified renders part of a tree in HTML starting at the node you specify.  The BackendPro interface must render hierarchical data somewhere.

**EDIT**: Nested sets are *not* a MySQL-only concept, but there is a good article about nested sets and MySQL here:

http://mikehillyer.com/articles/managing-hierarchical-data-in-mysql/

Comment: @Andy, thanks for the Nested sets link! **Very** useful and pretty slick! :-)